# Mass export all images as individual JPEGs in InDesign?

Tags: scripting, batch-processing, adobe-indesign

I am new to Indesign. I have a file that contains images with Photoshop clipping paths. I want to export all the clipped images in a folder. I have tried doing the "Copy Links To" and it successfully exported the original images. However, I do not want the original images but the clipped images instead. Is there a way for me to export all the clipped images as JPEG and not the original linked image? In short, I want to export the images without their background. I hope I'm making sense. I have about 800-1000 images so a batch processing method would be highly appreciated.

I found this script from one of the posts here and modified it a bit to suit my needs. It appears to work in most of my INDD documents, but it fails in others. I wonder why. I sometimes get the error message that
    Error string: null is not an object
    Source: fileName = File ( rect.graphics[0].itemLink.filePath ).name;

I also noticed that it skips some objects and won't download all of the images. I guess it skips those that are not in rectangles.

```
test();
function test()
{
var myDoc = app.activeDocument,
apis = myDoc.allPageItems, rect, fileName;

while ( rect = apis.pop() )
{
if ( !(rect instanceof Rectangle) || !rect.graphics[0].isValid ){ continue;}


fileName = File ( rect.graphics[0].itemLink.filePath ).name;
fileName = fileName.replace( /\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i, '.jpg' );


app.jpegExportPreferences.exportResolution = 2400;
app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegQuality = JPEGOptionsQuality.MAXIMUM;


//give it a unique name
var myFile = new File ("C:/Users/RANFacistol-Mata/Desktop/Image Trial/"+ fileName);


rect.exportFile(ExportFormat.JPG, myFile);
}
}
```

Is there a way for me to modify this script such that instead of iterating through all the rectangles, I would iterate through all of the objects instead, much like clicking this next button [image]

And then check if that object contains an image (jpg, tiff, psd, ai, eps). If it does, then I will export it as scripted above.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the links present inside the document with the following snippet, this will take less time as taken by the snippet above...
You can also get the type of link ('eps' or ' pdf' etc) with linkType attribute and filePath with 'filePath' attribute of each link object..

```
var theDoc = app.documents.item(0);
var theLinkLen = theDoc.links.length; 
for(var i = 0; i < theLinkLen; ++i)
{
  var link = theDoc.links.item(i);
  alert("link name \"" + link.name + "\"" + " has type \"" + link.linkType  + "\""+ " with filePath \"" + link.filePath + "\"");
}
```